# nested fields in simple_form is creating associations similar to Has_many through. By passing ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm trying to build associations using nested modals and checkboxes. However, its passing the relationship as ids and not how nested fields should pass.

Console looks like this:

```
Started POST "/campaigns/2/applicants" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-09 12:50:18 +0100
Processing by ApplicantsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rBfc+eoP4/nUr3Y7g4G/k7Kr/cOhdpnfQ5ImWaHalS4=", "applicant"=>{"cover_letter"=>"", "post_url"=>"", "campaign_id"=>"2", "applicant_commissions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"campaign_commission_id"=>["6", "5", ""]}}}, "commit"=>"Submit", "campaign_id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Campaign Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "campaigns".* FROM "campaigns"  WHERE "campaigns"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "applicants" ("campaign_id", "cover_letter", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["campaign_id", 2], ["cover_letter", ""], ["created_at", "2015-07-09 11:50:18.112084"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-09 11:50:18.112084"], ["user_id", 1]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "applicant_commissions" ("applicant_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["applicant_id", 41], ["created_at", "2015-07-09 11:50:18.115908"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-09 11:50:18.115908"]]
   (1.2ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/campaigns/2
Completed 302 Found in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
```

I have the following models

```
CampaignCommission.rb

class CampaignCommission < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :commission

  has_many :applicant_commissions
  has_many :applicants, through: :applicant_commissions
end

ApplicantCommission.rb

class ApplicantCommission < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

  belongs_to :applicant
  belongs_to :campaign_commission

  has_many :invoice_parts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :applicant
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :campaign_commission

end


Applicant.rb

class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :site
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :applicant_commissions
  #has_many :campaign_commissions, through: :applicant_commissions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :applicant_commissions
end
```

While a `User` is making an application (`Applicant`) I'd like them to select multiple `CampaignCommissions` from the available list (checkbox) which will populate the `ApplicantCommission` modal (one `CampaignCommission` per row).

This is similar to building a has_many through relationship, however with that, I cannot remove `applicants` or `ApplicantCommissions` without the `CampaignCommission` deleting.

```
  <div class="form-inputs">

  <%= f.input :cover_letter %>

  <%= f.input :post_url %>

  <%= f.input :campaign_id, :as => :hidden, :value => @campaign.id %>

    <p class="">What incentive would you like to receive?<br />(Please tick at least 1)</p>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :applicant_commissions do |p| %>
        <%= p.association :campaign_commission, collection: CampaignCommission.where(campaign: @campaign), as: :check_boxes %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
```

This is passing in the IDs, but only saving one row (with nothing in it)

So I'm trying to build an applicant_commission, but populate it with available campaign_commissions, which seems to be the problem.